# How do you prevent consecutive URLs in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Let's say you click something like `<Link to="/">{...}</Link>` twice. You will push the `"/"` pathname twice onto the `history.location`. How would you go about preventing the same pathname being pushed onto `history.location` two times in a row? Is this a bad UX?

Comment: What happens in your browser when you click twice on the title of this page? I'd expect the same to happen with JS using the `History` API.

Comment: use this link to customize history:https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Exactly what my question is asking how to do?

Comment: No, you have two questions. I asked something about one of them, specifically "Is this a bad UX?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<Link>` tags in `react-router-dom` have a `replace` boolean parameter. You can check the current pathname if it matches with the incoming pathname.

```
<Link to="/" replace={location.pathname === "/"}>...</Link>
```

You can check it out https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/replace-bool